# How to extract string value using perl regex function?

Tags: regex, perl

```
my $test = "&lt;test1&gt;INVOICE STATUS&lt";
```

I tried with regex  as  :

```
if ( $test =~  m/(&lt;.*.&gt;)/g){
print "matched $1";
}
```

The output obtained was `"lt;test1&gt;".`

Can any one suggest the right function to be used, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
/&gt;([^&]+)&lt;\//g
```

Example:

```
$_ = "&lt;test1&gt;INVOICE STATUS&lt;/test1&gt;&lt;test2&gt;NON-PO INVOICE&lt;/test2&gt;<o:p></o:p></b></p><p class=MsoPlainText><b>&lt;test3&gt;please specify&lt;/test3&gt;<o:p></o:p></b></p><p class=MsoPlainText><b>&lt;test4&gt;please specify&lt;/test&gt;";

while(/&gt;([^&]+)&lt;\//g){
        print "$1\n";
}
```

Output:

```
INVOICE STATUS
NON-PO INVOICE
please specify
please specify
```

Answer (score 0):

`/([-a-zA-Z]\s[a-zA-Z])/g`

First word matches letters or -, space, second word only letters.

EDIT: Or `/&gt;(.*?)&lt;/g`

you have the brackets reversed from how you want them in your original regex.

Answer (score 0):

`$1` contains the last match of the first capturing group, which is delimited by `(` and `)`.

Try : `/&lt;(.*.)&gt;/` instead.